# XOR calculator in perl array with output from xor cal

Tags: perl

how to make basic function for xor with array

example:
my $a = "08 F6";
my $b = "4C 6E";

output should be = 44 98

like http://xor.pw/?

Comment: Note that one shouldn't use `$a` and `$b`. It can interfere with `sort` and other subs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using xor on strings:

```
my $x_hex = '08 F6';
my $y_hex = '4C 6E';

my $x = pack('(H2)*', split(' ', $x_hex));   # my $x = "\x08\xF6";
my $y = pack('(H2)*', split(' ', $y_hex));   # my $y = "\x4C\x6E";

my $z = $x ^ $y;                             # my $z = "\x44\x98";

my $z_hex = join(' ', unpack('(H2)*', $z));  # my $z_hex = "44 98";
```

Using xor on numbers:

```
my $x_hex = '08 F6';
my $y_hex = '4C 6E';

my @x = map { hex($_) } split(' ', $x_hex);            # my @x = ( 0x08, 0xF6 );
my @y = map { hex($_) } split(' ', $y_hex);            # my @y = ( 0x4C, 0x6E );

my @z = map { $x[$_] ^ $y[$_] } 0..$#x;                # my @z = ( 0x44, 0x98 );

my $z_hex = join ' ', map { sprintf("%02X", $_) } @z;  # my $z_hex = "44 98";
```